# Label and ProgressBar doesn't update macOS Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, label, progress-bar

I have a problem with my code today. I try to update a label and a progress view inside a for loop, but neither the label or the progress bar update.

I can't understand why ... Here is the code if you can deal with it

```
    func parseMessage()
    {
        var i = 0

        self.beginHTML()

        for row in (try? db?.prepare("SELECT message.text, message.is_from_me, datetime(substr(message.date, 1, 9) + 978307200, 'unixepoch', 'localtime') as f_date, message.cache_has_attachments, message.ROWID FROM message LEFT JOIN chat WHERE chat.guid LIKE '%PHONENUMBER%' AND chat.ROWID == message.handle_id"))!!
        {
            html += """
            <div class=\"clear\"></div>
            <p align=\"center\"> \(String(describing: row[2] ?? "")) </p>
            """

            if (row[3] as! Int64 == 1)
            {
                self.parseAttachments(row: row)
            }
            else if (row[1] as! Int64 == 1)
            {
                html += "<div class=\"from-me\"> <p>\(String(describing: row[0] ?? "")) </p></div>"
            }
            else
            {
                html += "<div class=\"from-them\"> <p>\(String(describing: row[0] ?? "")) </p></div>"
            }

            i = i + 1

            if (i % 500 == 0)
            {
                self.progressLabel.stringValue = "\(i) on \(self.messageNumber)"
                self.progressBar.increment(by: 500)

//                DispatchQueue.main.async {
//                    self.progressLabel.stringValue = "\(i) on \(self.messageNumber)"
//                    self.progressBar.increment(by: 500)
//                }
            }

            if (i == 2000)
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        html += "</section></body></html>"
    }
```

My whole code is here: https://github.com/ExPl0siF/iOSMessageExport/blob/master/MessageGenerator/ViewController.swift

Comment: Is your parse method called on a background thread? If so, you want to get the main queue to update the UI.

Comment: I dont't know... But I test both puting DispatchQueue or not, and it doen't change anything ... You can see my commented code with DispatchQueue. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't run a for loop on the main thread and have UI updates show up. UI changes don't take place until your code returns and the app services the main event loop.

Conversely, if the code you posted is running on a background thread (which it probably should be) then you need to wrap the UI updates (changes to your labels and progress bar) in calls to `DispatchQueue.main.async()`

### EDIT: Try this change:

```
func parseMessage()
{
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        var i = 0
        
        self.beginHTML()
        
        for row in (try? db?.prepare("SELECT message.text, message.is_from_me, datetime(substr(message.date, 1, 9) + 978307200, 'unixepoch', 'localtime') as f_date, message.cache_has_attachments, message.ROWID FROM message LEFT JOIN chat WHERE chat.guid LIKE '%PHONENUMBER%' AND chat.ROWID == message.handle_id"))!!
        {
            html += """
            <div class=\"clear\"></div>
            <p align=\"center\"> \(String(describing: row[2] ?? "")) </p>
            """
            
            if (row[3] as! Int64 == 1)
            {
                self.parseAttachments(row: row)
            }
            else if (row[1] as! Int64 == 1)
            {
                html += "<div class=\"from-me\"> <p>\(String(describing: row[0] ?? "")) </p></div>"
            }
            else
            {
                html += "<div class=\"from-them\"> <p>\(String(describing: row[0] ?? "")) </p></div>"
            }
            
            i = i + 1
            
            if (i % 500 == 0)
            {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.progressLabel.stringValue = "\(i) on \(self.messageNumber)"
                    self.progressBar.increment(by: 500)
                }
            }
            
            if (i == 2000)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        
        html += "</section></body></html>"
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I see that on internet, so I try to fix it with a DispatchQueue like you said (as you can see in my commented code) but it didn't work too, this is why is so strange ...

Comment: Is your code to parse the HTML running on the main thread or on a background thread?

Comment: If you don't know, add code like this: `print("is main thread =", Thread.isMainThread)`

Comment: I get: is main thread = true so i admit my code already run on main thread, that's really strange, I can post my whole code if you want more information? Thanks

Comment: You need to post at least enough code to explain how your `parseMessage()` function is being called.

Comment: Here is my whole code: https://github.com/ExPl0siF/iOSMessageExport/blob/master/MessageGenerator/ViewController.swift

Comment: There is no reason that your parsing would be done on a background thread. You wrote it to run on the main thread. See the edit to my answer above.

Comment: Thank you very much !!! You made my day, coding for macOS is strange in comparison of iOS ...

Comment: The same rules about foreground/background threads apply to both platforms. In fact I responded to your question as a Swift question and didn't even notice that it was MacOS-specific. GCD is identical. The label and view objects are different, and view objects and design patterns are different, but the same idea of "Do time consuming tasks on a background thread and update the UI on the main thread" applies to both.